# What is scope.$$childHead?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript

I decided it's time for me to explore the hidden side of testing directives, and now when I do something with a directive that has an isolated scope:

```js
parentScope = $rootScope.$new()
parentScope.dasDingy = "bla bla dingy"
element = angular.element("<foo dingy='dasDingy'></foo>")
$compile(element)(parentScope)
$rootScope.$digest()

scope = angular.element(element).scope()
console.log(scope.dingy) //  is undefined --- Nah, ain't exist
//  but, if I do
console.log(scope.$$childHead.dingy) // it exists and it's == 'bla bla dingy'
```

So, what the heck is `scope.$$childHead` and why it is not accessible directly on scope? 
or maybe I'm doing something stupid here?

Comment: Angular properties starting with `$$` – are inner and are about to change in future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case `scope.$$childHead` is the isolated scope of the `<foo>` directive. See [here in the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/075ba901f62da43a0e87a95945e4e91e9f721e81/src/ng/rootScope.js#L173) where and when `this.$$childHead` is assigned. See the console output in [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EKPP3ALK4CV5rvdJqReS?p=preview) for examples using directives with diferent types of scope (shared, isolated, new).

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use (in the above example) element.isolateScope() instead of accessing $$childHead directly?

Comment: @StevenRogers I think using `element.isolateScope()` is preferable; In the following example, `$$childHead` may not target the expected element: http://jsfiddle.net/3agvyp8t/2/